# Pthred in php- works with browser but not in command line

Tags: php, command-line, pthreads

I installed pthread extension for php.
it works fine in chrome browser.
But when i try to run php script in like below command, it will not work and give fatal error.

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\thread\t.php

the error is "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Thread' not found in C:\wamp\www\thread\t.php on line 3"

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question, but I've got an answer (I didn't find it by google it).
You loaded the module only from the Apache php.ini so you need to also load the pthreads from the CLI php.ini (on Debian is under /etc/php5/cli/php.ini).

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not doing that any more. I will try when I free.